# JQuery Dialog Resizable containment

Tags: jquery, html, css, jquery-ui-dialog, jquery-ui-resizable

I am trying to add a draggable and resizable containment to a JQuery Dialog. I have found other issues and answers about draggable and resizable. However in combination with the Dialog it remains an issue.

Therefor i have altered one of the Fiddles i found here.

html:

```
<div id="ParentDIV">
    <div class="dragClass">
        <p>Drag me around!</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

JQuery:

```
$(".dragClass").dialog().parent()
.draggable({
    cursor: "move",
    delay: 100,
    containment: "#ParentDIV",
    scroll: false
})
.resizable({
    containment: '#ParentDIV'
});
```

css:

```
#ParentDIV {
    position: relative;
    margin: 50px 0 0 50px;
    width:500px;
    height:200px;
    background:lightgray;
}
.dragClass {
    font-family: Tahoma, sans;
    color: black;
    background: orange;
    border: 1px solid orange;
    width: 10em;
    height:auto;
    padding: 0.5em;
}
textarea {
    font-family: inherit;
    color: inherit;
    background: transparent;
    border: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    resize: none;
}
.ui-resizable-helper {
    border: 2px dotted #00F;
}
```

fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/v4zfc8uc/

The problem is that when you try to resize the dialog when the containment area has a margin, the Dialog still acts like there is no margin.

The draggable containment seems to be doing it's job.